# RapidMiner Union over Collection (of Data Tables)

Tags: join, collections, union, rapidminer

I am having a hard time finding a solution for doing a Union over a Collection of Data Tables in Rapid Miner (6).
I basically have a Collection (in case you don't know it, imagine it as an array of objects) that contains a variable number of Data Tables, each having at least one "id" column with the same id + another column with a different name in each.
I want to merge all these in as Union (aka Join), as to have records of the form [id, column_from_data_table_1, column_from_data_table2, ...].

For example, the collection would contain a number N of data tables of the form:

```
Table 1
id  col1
 1   0.5
 2   0.7

Table 2
id  col2
 1   0.1
 2   0.0

........
........
........

Table N
id colN
 1  0.0
 2  0.8
```

And at the end, the union (join) of the tables in the collection should look like this:

```
Result
id col1 col2 ... colN
 1  0.5  0.1 ...  0.0
 2  0.7  0.0 ...  0.8
```

Note that each table has the same number of records and the same ids assigned to them (+ column names across tables, except id, are unique - in other words, data couldn't be more ideal than this).

Answer (score 1):

Quite an advanced process involving `Remember`, `Recall`, `Branch`, `Join`, `Select` and `Loop Collection`. Here's a cut down example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="6.1.008">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="subprocess" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="76" name="Subprocess" width="90" x="112" y="30">
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="60" name="Generate Data by User Specification" width="90" x="45" y="30">
            <list key="attribute_values">
                   <parameter key="id" value="1"/>
              <parameter key="col1" value="48"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles">
              <parameter key="id" value="id"/>
            </list>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="60" name="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" width="90" x="45" y="120">
            <list key="attribute_values">
              <parameter key="id" value="2"/>
              <parameter key="col1" value="4"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles">
              <parameter key="id" value="id"/>
            </list>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="append" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="94" name="Append" width="90" x="179" y="30"/>
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="60" name="Generate Data by User Specification (3)" width="90" x="45" y="210">
            <list key="attribute_values">
              <parameter key="id" value="1"/>
              <parameter key="col2" value="9"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles">
              <parameter key="id" value="id"/>
            </list>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="60" name="Generate Data by User Specification (4)" width="90" x="45" y="300">
            <list key="attribute_values">
              <parameter key="id" value="2"/>
              <parameter key="col2" value="7"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles">
              <parameter key="id" value="id"/>
            </list>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="append" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="94" name="Append (2)" width="90" x="179" y="210"/>
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="60" name="Generate Data by User Specification (5)" width="90" x="45" y="390">
            <list key="attribute_values">
              <parameter key="id" value="1"/>
              <parameter key="col3" value="88"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles">
              <parameter key="id" value="id"/>
            </list>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="60" name="Generate Data by User Specification (6)" width="90" x="45" y="480">
            <list key="attribute_values">
              <parameter key="id" value="2"/>
              <parameter key="col3" value="78"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles">
              <parameter key="id" value="id"/>
            </list>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="append" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="94" name="Append (3)" width="90" x="179" y="390"/>
          <operator activated="true" class="collect" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="112" name="Collect" width="90" x="380" y="210"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 1"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 2"/>
          <connect from_op="Append" from_port="merged set" to_op="Collect" to_port="input 1"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (3)" from_port="output" to_op="Append (2)" to_port="example set 1"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (4)" from_port="output" to_op="Append (2)" to_port="example set 2"/>
          <connect from_op="Append (2)" from_port="merged set" to_op="Collect" to_port="input 2"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (5)" from_port="output" to_op="Append (3)" to_port="example set 1"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (6)" from_port="output" to_op="Append (3)" to_port="example set 2"/>
          <connect from_op="Append (3)" from_port="merged set" to_op="Collect" to_port="input 3"/>
          <connect from_op="Collect" from_port="collection" to_port="out 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_in 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_out 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_out 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="multiply" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="94" name="Multiply (2)" width="90" x="246" y="30"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="select" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="60" name="Select (2)" width="90" x="447" y="30"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="remember" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="60" name="Remember" width="90" x="581" y="30">
        <parameter key="name" value="1"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="loop_collection" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="76" name="Loop Collection" width="90" x="447" y="165">
        <parameter key="set_iteration_macro" value="true"/>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="branch" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="76" name="Branch" width="90" x="112" y="120">
            <parameter key="condition_type" value="expression"/>
            <parameter key="condition_value" value="%{iteration}==1"/>
            <process expanded="true">
              <connect from_port="condition" to_port="input 1"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_condition" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_input 1" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_input 2" spacing="0"/>
            </process>
            <process expanded="true">
              <operator activated="true" class="recall" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="60" name="Recall" width="90" x="112" y="75">
                <parameter key="name" value="1"/>
              </operator>
              <operator activated="true" class="join" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="76" name="Join" width="90" x="246" y="30">
                <list key="key_attributes"/>
              </operator>
              <operator activated="true" class="remember" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="60" name="Remember (2)" width="90" x="380" y="30">
                <parameter key="name" value="1"/>
              </operator>
              <connect from_port="condition" to_op="Join" to_port="left"/>
              <connect from_op="Recall" from_port="result" to_op="Join" to_port="right"/>
              <connect from_op="Join" from_port="join" to_op="Remember (2)" to_port="store"/>
              <connect from_op="Remember (2)" from_port="stored" to_port="input 1"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_condition" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_input 1" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_input 2" spacing="0"/>
            </process>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="single" to_op="Branch" to_port="condition"/>
          <connect from_op="Branch" from_port="input 1" to_port="output 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_single" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="recall" compatibility="6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="60" name="Recall (2)" width="90" x="581" y="165">
        <parameter key="name" value="1"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Subprocess" from_port="out 1" to_op="Multiply (2)" to_port="input"/>
      <connect from_op="Multiply (2)" from_port="output 1" to_op="Select (2)" to_port="collection"/>
      <connect from_op="Multiply (2)" from_port="output 2" to_op="Loop Collection" to_port="collection"/>
      <connect from_op="Select (2)" from_port="selected" to_op="Remember" to_port="store"/>
      <connect from_op="Recall (2)" from_port="result" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I noticed a possible error in the process above - it was created using the limited availability cloud version so may not load into the normal standalone version. To fix it change "6.1.000-SNAPSHOT" to "6.0.008"